# d3 js world map with pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, topojson

I have plotted world map with pie charts on top of it using d3 v3 and topojson v0.
I have an data

```
var sampleData = {
    "data":[
        {
            "lat": "20.593684",
            "lon": "78.9629"
        },
        {
            "lat": "51.52807562568998",
            "lon": "4.922901059462091"
        }
    ],
    "pieData": [
        [10,20,50],
        [30,60,65]
    ]
```

}

I need to use sampleData.pieData to plot pie charts.

```
jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/aumy37nc/
```

i can plot pie charts for data sets 
'var pieChartData = [10,20,50]';
but instead i need to plot data based on values from

```
'sampleData.pieData'
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use `sampleData.pieData[0])` because you need to access the child. Please check if this you want.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jRg1Iu5CIdk5kux0MMy2?p=preview